# How to resubscribe a user in Marketing cloud using SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I have unsubscribed users using logunusbevent call in a custom unsubscribe landing pages. However, I couldn't resubscribe them again if they check the resubscribe checkbox, below are the codes that I have tried and I am trying to activate a subscriber in all subscriber list but the below codes are not working

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
         Platform.Load("Core","1");
         var subscriber = {"EmailTypePreference": "HTML","Attributes":{"First Name": "Test11", "Last Name": "User11","Status"  :"Active"}

};

var subObj = Subscriber.Init("subkey");
var status = subObj.Update(subscriber);
Write("Help"+status);

var myList = List.Init("All Subscribers - 9899");
var status1 = myList.Subscribers.Update("subkkey","Active");
Write("Help"+status1);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. It will update profile attributes & status both for all subscriber list.

```
<script  runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");
var subkey = "abc123";
var subObj = Subscriber.Init(subkey); 
var subs = subObj.Lists.Retrieve(); 
//Write(Stringify(subs) + "<br>");   // for test purpose

for (var i = 0; i < subs.length; i++) 
{
  // Write(subs[i].List.ID + "<br>"); // for test purpose   
  if(subs[i].Status == "Unsubscribed") // search for Unsubscribed in  all subscriber list one by one
  {                
        var testSubscriber = {              
            "SubscriberKey": subkey,
            "Attributes":{"First Name": "Test11", "Last Name": "Test"},
            "Lists": {"Status": "Active","ID": subs[i].List.ID, "Action": "Update"}
        };      
        var subObj1 = Subscriber.Init(subkey);
        var status = subObj1.Update(testSubscriber); 
        Write("status=" + status + "<br>");
  }  
} 
</script>
```

In  above mentioned code, I am assuming that the user's subscriber key is available to process (same as your ref. code).

> Note : List ID should be passed to re-subscribe user from all subscriber list

Steps:

> Step-1. Create a object of subscriber

```
var subObj = Subscriber.Init(subkey);
```

> Step-2. Retrieve all subscriber list

```
var subs = subObj.Lists.Retrieve();
```

> Step-3. Iterate for all available records of Subscriber list

`for (var i = 0; i < subs.length; i++)
  // Write(subs[i].List.ID + "<br>"); // for test purpose`

> Step-4. Create user object for each subscriber list to update

```
var testSubscriber = {              
        "SubscriberKey": subkey, //1
        "Attributes":{"First Name": "Test11", "Last Name": "Test"}, //2
        "Lists": {"Status": "Active","ID": subs[i].List.ID, "Action": "Update"} //3
   };
```

> Note:
>
> 1.(required) SubscriberKey is required field for update Subscriber
>
> 2.(Optional) If you want to update Attributes then pass all attributes as key value pair
>
> 3.(required in case of list) Pass Status, Id(ListId) & action that will perform on subscriber

```
//
```

> Step-5. Create a new 'Subscribers' object to update

```
var subObj1 = Subscriber.Init(subkey);
```

> 6. Update user reord

```
var status = subObj1.Update(testSubscriber);
```

Comment: This code work fine  only on Parent BU apparently. Are there a way to retrieve and upddate records in All Subscribers list in Child BUs ?

Comment: Hi, you can follow these link. [1.link](https://gortonington.com/wsproxy-upsert-subscribers-from-a-data-extension/)  [2.link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/266540/45866)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kumar - I have tried your solution and I was unable to make it work.
On Step 4, I've actually modified the object and it's working now - It might help other developers

```
var testSubscriber = {              
   "SubscriberKey": subkey, //1
   // NOT USED - "Attributes":{"First Name": "Test11", "Last Name": "Test"},
   "Lists": {"ID": subs[i].List.ID, "Action": "Update"}, //3
   "Status": "Active"
};
```