# How can I obtain the Business Unit level All Subscribers Status from the Top Level Business Unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

I'm trying to get a list of Unsubscribed subscribers at BU level, per BU in the enterprise.

I've managed to find the All Subscribers ListID per BU using the following code:

```
<script runat = "server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1.1.5");

var proxy = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var queryAllAccounts = true; // this is important otherwise you just get the parent BU 

function retrieveBUName(id) {
    var cols = ["ID", "Name"];
    var filter = {
        Property: "ID",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: id
    };
    var retrieveResults = proxy.retrieve("Account", cols, filter, queryAllAccounts);
    return (retrieveResults.Results[0].Name)

}

function retrieveListID() {
    var AllSubscriberObj = [];
    var listName = "All Subscribers"
    var cols = ["ID", "Client.ID","ListName"];
    var filter = {
        Property: "ListName",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: listName
    };
    var retrieveResults = proxy.retrieve("List", cols, filter, queryAllAccounts);
    for (var i = 0; i < retrieveResults.Results.length; i++) {
        var result = {}
        result["BUMID"] = retrieveResults.Results[i]["Client"]["ID"]
        result["BUName"] = retrieveBUName(retrieveResults.Results[i]["Client"]["ID"])
        result["AllSubscriberListID"] = retrieveResults.Results[i]["ID"]
        result["ListName"] = retrieveResults.Results[i]["ListName"]
        AllSubscriberObj.push(result)
    }
    return (AllSubscriberObj)
}

var result = retrieveListID()
Write(Stringify(result))

</script>
```

Result

```
[
  {
    "BUMID": 11111111,
    "BUName": "Avocado",
    "AllSubscriberListID": 137,
    "ListName": "All Subscribers"
  },
  {
    "BUMID": 2222222222,
    "BUName": "Banana",
    "AllSubscriberListID": 350,
    "ListName": "All Subscribers"
  },
  {
    "BUMID": 3333333333,
    "BUName": "Cabbage",
    "AllSubscriberListID": 352,
    "ListName": "All Subscribers"
  }
]
```

But when I query the ListID and Client.ID directly using the following code on the ListSubscriber object, it runs for a bit of time but doesn't return any results.  This same code works for other ListID's in the BU.

```
<script runat = "server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1.1.5");
var proxy = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var queryAllAccounts = true;

var filter = {
    LeftOperand: {
        Property: "ListID",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: "137" //BU Level All Subscribers List ID from result above
    },
    LogicalOperator: "AND",
    RightOperand: {
        Property: "Client.ID",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: "1054024"
    }
}

var cols = ["ListID", "SubscriberKey", "Status", "Client.ID"];

var listSubscriberResults = proxy.retrieve("ListSubscriber", cols, filter, queryAllAccounts);
Write(Stringify(listSubscriberResults))
```

Results

```
{"Status":"OK","RequestID":"e9dcfac6-fc21-49c4-af4a-7cb09549e412","Results":[],"HasMoreRows":false}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use the "[Subscriber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/subscriber.htm)" object instead of "ListSubscriber". The other thing to note is that the retrieve request will only return 2500 records at a time, but you can use the [getNextBatch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_advanced_retrieve.htm) function to continue paginating through the results if you have more than that. Consider running in a Script Activity within an Automation if you have lots of subscribers. Also, instead of pushing to arrays, you could alternatively add rows to Data Extension(s) to record your data.

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");

    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    // arrays for your unsubscribers
    var avocadoUnsubs = [];
    var bananaUnsubs = [];
    var cabbageUnsubs = [];
    // query all BUs
    var queryAllAccounts = true;
    // set the attributes to be retrieved
    var cols = ["SubscriberKey","Status","Client.ID"];
    var filter = {
        Property: "Status",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: "Unsubscribed"
    };
    var moreData = true;
    var reqID = null;
    var numUnSubs = 0;
    var results = [];
    while(moreData) {
        moreData = false;
        // WSProxy retrieve or getNextBatch
        var data = reqID == null ?
            prox.retrieve("Subscriber", cols, filter, queryAllAccounts) : 
            prox.getNextBatch("Subscriber", reqID);

        if(data != null) {
            moreData = data.HasMoreRows;
            reqID = data.RequestID;
            if(data && data.Results) {
                numUnSubs += data.Results.length;
                for(var i=0; i< data.Results.length; i++) {
                    //Push the record to the right BU array
                    if (data.Results.Client.ID == '1111111111') {
                        avocadoUnsubs.push( data.Results.SubscriberKey );
                    }
                    if (data.Results.Client.ID == '2222222222') {
                        bananaUnsubs.push( data.Results.SubscriberKey );
                    }
                    if (data.Results.Client.ID == '3333333333') {
                        cabbageUnsubs.push( data.Results.SubscriberKey );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Write("Number of unsubs: " + numUnSubs);
    Write("<br>Number of avocado unsubs: " +  avocadoUnsubs.length);
    Write("<br>Number of banana unsubs: " + bananaUnsubs.length);
    Write("<br>Number of cabbage unsubs: " + cabbageUnsubs.length);
</script>
```